# How to add a note after we start the bounty

Tags: support

I started a bounty for *[Google Charts Legend Position Top Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49774593/google-charts-legend-position-top-not-working)*.

It had an answer, but according to the OP (the user who posted the answer) has mentioned that following note.

> note: the only advantage to material is having multiple stacks, in
>   classic, you cannot group multiple stacks...

Actually, it is my question about grouping multiple stacks...

But I forget to mention that when placing a bounty, the below answer won't solve my question since I need to group multiple stacks.

So is there way to add that note now? Or is it OK to edit the question and add that note?

Comment: I don't think there is. Either leave a comment or ask a mod to refund it (Tavern on the Meta, although I doubt they will actually do it)

Comment: As it is you own question and *my question [is] about group multiple stacks...* seems to be relevant to what you ask so that clarification should be in the post. Once the bounty runs out the  notice will be gone and so will that extra valuable hint.

Comment: You can't. The bounty notice is not editable.

Comment: Also see [Can we have a way to edit bounty custom message?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/112188) on Meta.SE.